# Comparing value types cast to object

Tags: c#, casting, boolean, equality, value-type

I have a method which returns an object, which could be one of a number of different data types, including strings, numbers and bools; and at some point I need to compare the equality of two values returned from this method. I'm using `==` instead of `Equals()` because I need different number types to compare - ie. `3 == 3.0` - which is working fine for strings and numbers, but for some reason it falls down when I'm comparing boolean values.

What would be the best way to solve this problem? I'd prefer not to have to detect the type and cast if bool, but I will do if there is no other solution

My code looks something like:

```
private object GetValue() {
    // does some stuff, returns either a boolean, string or number value
}

var value1 = GetValue();
var value2 = GetValue();
if (value1 == value2) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `==` will not work for you.  Period. `(object)"a" ==new String(new[]{'a'})` is false.

Comment: Yeah I get that, what would you propose instead?

Comment: (object)1 == (object)1.0 false .net 4.0

Comment: Did you try creating 3 seperate functions (overload), each to return the correct type instead of having to use Object? Or maybe creating some base generic class to accept T?

Comment: This is generally a trivial problem with the exception that you're assuming different types will, sometimes, need to be considered equal.  If you could convert all of your numeric types to a single type (i.e. convert all integer types to `double`) then the problem would be trivial, just use `object.Equals`.

Comment: @GregOks Well, that would be a lot of options, since you need to compare an int to a double and have it sometimes be equal.  You wouldn't just need 3, you'd need to account for each permutation of each pair of numeric types.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly crap you're right. I've amended my question to show a better example of the code I'm using. I have tests where GetValue returns an int and a double, and the equality works correctly

Comment: @JordanWallwork can you provide more details what the function GetValue() does? It's just seems that you can work out some other solution and not return Object..

Comment: @JordanWallwork What are all of the numeric types that you have?  Is it just int and double, is it any of the possible numeric types?

Comment: Can you describe what `GetValue` does, and can it be changed?

Comment: GetValue basically parses and evaluates a DSL and returns the result, and the dsl can return any value. Can't be changed unfortunately

Comment: @JordanWallwork see if my last edit helps you out or gets you to the right direction at least :)

Comment: But isn't there some metadata along? Doesn't the method *know* the type at the moment of parsing? It's a bit strange that you are considering `(int)1` to be equal to `(double)1.0`, since these are probably results of different functions, right?

Comment: No there's no metadata. The method doesnt parse the scripts directly, and doesn't have access to the AST, it simply calls something which executes the scripts and then determines whether they match. It's not ideal, but some functions return floats (such as some division functions) but the dsl interprets numbers as integers, and I don't have control over the dsl or the interpreter, I just have to deal with the returned values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public bool Compare(object value1, object value2)
{
    if (value1.GetType() == value2.GetType())
    {
        return value1.Equals(value2);
    }
    else
    {
        //your logic for handling different numbers
    }
}
```

Comment: It still feels a little hacky, but I've ended up using this, and just doing a ToString when the types don't match. I'm not wholly pleased, but at least all my tests are passing now :)

Answer (score 0):

How about make your function to return string and then just parse the result to bool or int or whatever you want and then compare?

EDIT:

```
private string GetValue() {}

string val = getValue();
string val2 = getValue();

bool a1;
bool b1;
int a2;
int b2;
double;
double;

bool r1 = bool.TryParse(val, out a1);
bool r2 = bool.TryParse(val2, out b1);
bool r3 = int.TryParse(val, out a2);
bool r4 = int.TryParse(val2, out b2);
bool r5 = double.TryParse(val, out a3);
bool r6 = double.TryParse(val2, out b3);

if ((a1 == b1 && r1 && r2)) || (a2 == b2 && r3 && r4)) || (a3 == b3 && r5 && r6))
return true;
```

Comment: you don't need to assign the variables, since they will all be overwritten in the `TryParse` functions.

Comment: @Default you are right but I didnt want to have situation where the tryParse failed for both of the values and the result will be 0 = 0 which would return true...but I edited my answer so maybe now it seems better..